# Did Marriott International issue a statement stating that they would decline any requests to use their U.S. hotels as detention facilities?

Tags: united-states, politics

The following image has been floating around social media today (July 11, 2019) claiming to be a statement being made by Marriott International regarding them declining requests to use their U.S. hotels as detention facilities. The source seems to be [this tweet from SanctuaryDMV](https://twitter.com/SanctuaryDMV/status/1149427805471608834).

Is there any truth to this? Is this statement official? I can’t find it—or anything close to it—on [Marriott International’s official press/news center](https://news.marriott.com).

> [image: The “Statement of Marriott International” image that is circulating on social media.]

The image has a date of “July 11, 2019” and the text reads as follows:

> **Statement of Marriott International**
>
> “Marriott International has had no indication that any of our hotels have been contacted by the U.S. government to be used to detain individuals. Our hotels are not configured to be detention facilities, but to be open to guests and community members as well. While we have no particular insights into whether the U.S. government is considering the use of hotels to aid in the situation at the border, Marriott has made the decision to decline any requests to use our hotels as detention facilities.”

Comment: It seems like the tweet you linked is saying this was specifically sent to them?

Comment: FWIW, there are plausible reports that folks in other parts of the world are being "detained" on Marriott properties, by foreign governments possibly acting on behalf of US agencies.  But from my brief browsing these appear to be more of a "house arrest" situation.

Comment: This feels very "current events". It may take a few days for the facts to be established outside of "he said, she said".

Comment: A lot of people are pinging the Marriott account on Twitter, so if this isn't an official response, we can probably expect one soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right that Marriott International’s official press/news center does not include news of this statement. There was also no mention of it on Marriott International's own [Twitter](https://twitter.com/MarriottIntl?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor). It has been a few days and this is now reported by multiple news agencies, such as [ABC](https://abcnews.go.com/Business/marriott-choice-hotels-serve-detention-centers-ice-raids/story?id=64291249) and [Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/immigration-raids-ice-nine-cities-albence-1449121). It would be surprising if Marriott allowed the media to widely report this without releasing a statement saying [this](https://twitter.com/SanctuaryDMV/status/1149427805471608834) one is false.

I contacted Marriott International multiple times. I received a response from [Connie Kim](https://www.linkedin.com/in/connieleekim), "Vice President, Media Relations," confirming that the statement is Marriott's. I am willing to forward the response to you (ping me in chat).

To answer the question:

> Did Marriott International issue a statement stating that they would decline any requests to use their U.S. hotels as detention facilities?

**Yes, Marriott International did issue such a statement.** They included it in an email to me and I pasted it above.

Comment: This is some great research, but I wish there was a way to check it that didn't involve trusting you.  Even if you forward someone the email you received, we can't be sure you didn't fake it.  By the way, was there any explanation given as to why they didn't post the statement on their website with the rest of their press releases?

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree with your concerns. Why trust a random stranger on the internet? That said, I will reply to the email and ask why it wasn't posted on Marriott's website or twitter. I am also willing to forward the email to you. I am personally unsure how to fake emails (but why trust me?).

Comment: According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/e-mail-can-be-made-to-appear-like-it-came-from-a-big-organization) Security.SE question, "When the sender and the receiver both implement SPF, DKIM and DMARC properly then spoofing risk is greatly reduced." I can see right now that clicking on "show original" from more options in the email I received has a PASS written next to the SPF, DKIM, and DMARC lines. I cannot exactly say this means SPF, DKIM and DMARC have been implemented properly for both sender and receiver, etc. but I think if you dig deeper yourself you will

Comment: be more confident about the authenticity of the email. Again, willing to forward to you.

Comment: My response was not very concise and I sort of missed the point. " I wish there was a way to check it that didn't involve trusting you." Yes, I wish this too. "was there any explanation given as to why they didn't post the statement on their website?" No, there was no explanation. I just asked why. "Even if you forward someone the email you received, we can't be sure you didn't fake it." I am not sure if this statement is true. I will ask on Security.SE. *If this is true*, I don't know what else I can do. *If this is NOT true*, I can forward you the email.

Comment: For those interested, [now on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213594/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-authenticity-of-a-forwarded-email).

Comment: @NateEldredge Seems like you are right. I don't know what to say.

Comment: @JakeGould You're right. I might be over-reacting. I don't understand "people can lie via SSL."

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think there's anything I can do besides forwarding you the email.

Comment: I don't need to see it myself, but thanks for offering.  I'm more thinking philosophically.